# php/html link for switch tabs on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a mobile browser (android / Samsung browser) with x tabs:

> tab 1 = (myPage/index.php)
>  tab 2 = (google.com)
>  tab 3 =
>   (yahoo.com)
>  tab 4 = (myPage/home.php)
>  tab 5 =
>   (myPage/settings.php)
>  ... etc.

Is it possible for tab 10 (myPage/test.php) to have a link to reopen tab 4 (myPage/home.php) without opening a new tab?

Comment: This may be of help: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's only possible if `test.php` is parent of `home.php` Tab

```
var homeTab = window.open("myPage/home.php", "Home");

setTimeout(function(){
    homeTab.location.reload();
}, 2000);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6w5L7pau/)